# error received while converting a txt to csv

Tags: r, csv

I am attempting to convert a text file to a csv file using R because it is too big to open as a text file normally. The source file is space separated.

my current code is simply:

```
    data<-read.table("name.txt")
    x<-as.data.frame(data)
    write.csv(x,file="name2.csv")
```

The code works fine when I use another file, but when I use my target file I get the error code:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax,sep,dec,quote,skip,nlines,na.strings, :line 1 did not have 24 elements

What would cause this issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Add `fill = TRUE` to your `read.table()` call.  And if there is a header row, add `header = TRUE`.  Also, the second line is not necessary, as `read.table()` returns a data.frame.  But first, reading `help(read.table)` would be a good idea

Comment: Woo Woot! thanks! that did the trick!